# Problem with Zoom about QGrapphicsRectItem in View in Pyside6

Tags: qgraphicsview, pyside6, qgraphicsscene

I am new to PySide6, and I have the following code:

```
def wheelEvent(self, event):
    factor = 1.1
    if event.angleDelta().y() > 0:
        self.scale(factor, factor)
        self.scaleFactor *= factor
    else:
self.scale(round(1 / factor, 1), round(1 / factor, 1))
        self.scaleFactor /= factor
```

This code is used to scale the view, but when I use QGraphicsScene().addItem() to add a QGraphicsRectItem, the item scales when I zoom in, which I do not want. How can I resolve this issue?

i dont want the item do zoom in. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: If you want an item to ignore transformations, use the related `ItemIgnoresTransformations` flag.

Comment: but when i use this flag, every time when i do zoom in, the item changes the position, i dont know why

Comment: if you don't want the item to scale and you don't want the item to change position then don't scale the scene.

Comment: It probably is because you create the item by setting the geometry of the rectangle instead of setting the position. `item = QGraphicsRectItem(100, 100, 100, 100)` is not the same as `item = QGraphicsRectItem(0, 0, 100, 100)` followed by `item.setPos(100, 100)`. You need to read more carefully the documentation of QGraphicsScene and QGraphicsItem, especially what related to the [Graphics View Coordinate System](//doc.qt.io/qt-6/graphicsview.html#the-graphics-view-coordinate-system). In any case, if you need further help, we need you to provide an appropriate [mre] (please *do* read that link).

Comment: i hace resolved the problem, thank you very much, i need learn more XD

Comment: @Min Then I suggest you to delete this post, as there are plenty of related resources (even here on SO), and your question will hardly help anybody in any measure due to its specificity (and, controversially, its broadness).